# Reliable anti-theft configuration for laptop

Tags: laptop, remote-control, anti-theft

I just bought a new laptop and I want to prepare it in case it gets lost or stolen. I am focusing on the following features:

1. Remote administration
2. Prevent losing control

So far, I have thought about the following steps:

1. Disable USB ports and install administrator password in BIOS, to prevent other boot options.
2. Install remote tracking and administration service, to locate and maintain control over laptop.
3. Create a Guest account with limited access, to allow changing internet connection.

The only loophole I couldn't find a solution for is HDD replacement with a fresh copy of Windows or any other OS. Any solutions for that?

I am not interested on how to protect my data (encryption, backup etc), which is what similar threads discuss about.

In case of theft, I found it useful to have a photo copy of your laptop's identification stickers and registering your laptop. Laptop registration consists of creating an account on the manufacturer's website and providing the laptop's serial number. This, together with the purchase bill, can prove it's your laptop in case the police gets involved.

It would be nice to have a general solution, described for each individual OS platform (Windows, Macintosh, Linux). Here is an example for each step I provided earlier:

1. Same on Windows/Linux, but depends on BIOS capabilities. On Macintosh, I heard that the BIOS is not configurable.
2. A platform independent solution would be [Prey Project](https://preyproject.com).
3. On Macintosh, the built-in Guest account seems appropriate. Windows and Linux require creating a custom user with appropriate permissions.

In conclusion, how do I secure HDD replacement? Also, a completely different approach on this matter is welcomed.

Comment: Is this question off-topic simply because it asks for recommendation? I don't see how this subject will become outdated any time soon and the single answer given so far by @Tetsujin is not opinion-based because it is founded on Apple's T2 chip documentation. Also, I have described the situation and asked about a specific problem that I have: prevent storage replacement. Is the title not appropriate, including the last part with the example?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You've provided a well-written question.  I don't see it as requesting a product recommendation.  To me, it is asking about the potential to accomplish this and approaches for doing it.  So I disagree with the stated close reason, but it does have different issues.  1. If you were creating a self-answered canonical thread, the multiple platforms might be OK.  But the solution for each will be substantially different; even within the same hardware platform type.  That makes it overly broad as-is.  (cont'd)

Comment: 2. If you were looking for a specific, current solution for particular hardware, that would anchor the question to today's hardware.  That's not a great fit for a site that seeks information with long-term value.  3. If you are looking for general discussion on the subject, that isn't a good fit for a Q&A site.  So I think what you're asking is interesting, potentially useful, and well-presented.  I would be interested in good answers, myself, but I'm having trouble seeing how the question could be reframed to fit in this venue.  It's a good question, this just isn't the best place to ask it.

Comment: Thank you very much @fixer1234 for the extensive feedback. I really appreciate it because I am a feedback oriented person. I can now understand the problem with my question. Answers are likely to provide context specific solutions, which makes the question overly broad and difficult to chose an answer. I was expecting multiple partially correct answers when I wrote the question, but didn't pay attention on actually having to chose one. That's because many questions have multiple correct answers. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

idk if anyone other than Apple has this type of tech yet, but [Apple's T2 chip](https://www.apple.com/mac/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf) makes replacing the boot drive virtually impossible.
That most of their current laptops have soldered drives, not replaceable at all, makes this even less likely to happen.
Encryption is also tied directly to the hardware.
In essence, this is 'hardware encryption' like on an iPhone - steal it, you own a pretty brick.

*extract*

> The Apple T2 Security Chip provides a dedicated AES crypto engine
> built into the DMA path between the flash storage and main system
> memory, making internal volume encryption using
> FileVault with AES-XTS highly efficient.
>
> The Mac unique ID (UID) and a device group ID (GID) are AES 256-bit
> keys fused (UID) or compiled (GID) into the Secure Enclave during
> manufacturing.
> No software or firmware can read the keys directly. The keys can be
> used  only by the AES engine dedicated to the Secure Enclave. This
> dedicated  AES engine makes available only the results of encryption or
> decryption operations it performs. The UIDs and GIDs aren’t available
> via JTAG or other debugging interfaces.
>
> Because the UID is unique to
> each device and is generated wholly within the Secure Enclave rather
> than in a manufacturing system outside of the device, the UID key isn’t available for access or storage by Apple or any
> Apple suppliers. Software running on the Secure Enclave takes
> advantage of the UID to protect device-specific secrets such as Touch
> ID data, FileVault class keys, and the Keychain.
>
> The UID allows data to be cryptographically tied to a particular
> device. For example, the key hierarchy protecting the file system
> includes the UID, so if internal storage media are physically moved
> from one device to another, the files they contain are inaccessible.
> The UID isn’t related to any other identifier on the device. This
> architecture forms the basis for secure internal volume encryption.

Comment: I was also thinking about HDD encryption, but I'm not sure if it remains enabled if the HDD is replaced.

Comment: If the drive is encrypted, the data is 'safe'.The machine, on the other hand isn't, unless it has either a T2 or equivalent or the bios/EFI etc can also be locked down..  If the drive on a non-T2-type machine is swapped out, they own your machine. That's always been the problem until recently with laptops as opposed to phones.

Comment: That's also what I know so far. Hopefully, someone comes with a better answer. Also, at one of my workplaces, I had my Apple Mini's default HDD swapped with an ordinary SSD with success. It definitely didn't had Apple T2 at that time, but your exact says that the T2 chip is "highly efficient" and well secured. It doesn't say it won't work with replaced storage. It says that the FS needs the UID where the encryption was enabled. Does T2 support unencrypted storage?

Comment: Yes & no. You can leave the drive theoretically decrypted - but that actually only changes how the keys are stored. All this information is in the pdf I linked.

Comment: I looked over the PDF and I understand what you mean with the "yes & no" part. However, it says that the anti-replay mechanism only works when you set a FileVault password. This makes it is possible to mount another APFS storage drive with a password free Volume Key obtained from an replay attack. Yes, that's a lot of work and I think it's secure enough for an ordinary theft.